# R convert file size string "xxK/xxM/xxG" to numeric

Tags: r

I have some data looks like this:

```
data.text = "59M  20140805164405
117M  20140805175248
44M 20140805193627
34M 20140805201533
29M 20140805204604
...
20M 20140805223053
19M 20140805224844
18M 20140805230548
17M 20140805232212
12M 20140806005726
11M 20140806010816
11M 20140806011834
9.4M  20140806012822
8.9M  20140806013742
8.2M  20140806014626
...
944K  20140806053151
844K  20140806053322
352K  20140806054000"
```

And you can read in the data

```
data <- read.csv(text=data.text, sep='\t', header=FALSE, col.names=c("size", "timestamp"), )
```

Is there any package available in R to convert string like `8.2M` or `352K` into numeric bytes values like

```
result <- magic('8.2M')
result 
8200000 bytes
```

I think it will be good before writing my own function. 
Thanks!

Comment: The converse has a built-in function: `utils:::print.object_size`

Comment: ^^ `format.object_size` actually does the work

Answer (score 0):

This returns the file size in bytes

```r
a = function(x) {
  as.numeric(substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-1))*
  purrr::map_dbl(
    toupper(substr(x, nchar(x), nchar(x))), 
    ~{switch(.x, "K" = 1024, "M" = 1024^2, "G" = 1024^3, "T" = 1024^4)})
}

a(c("17m", "1g")) 
#  17825792 1073741824
```